# Monte Carlo Simulation (Triangular Distribution) across rows of CSV cost data

Tags: r, csv, montecarlo

I have a csv list containing cost estimates with each row containing a lower (l), central (c) and upper (u) range estimate for each line item estimate which is prepared in excel by non R users. An example of the CSV data which i have read into R is as follows:

```
         Item     l     c     u
        <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 “CostItem1”  1500  1900  2600
2 “CostItem2”  2400  3200  4400
3 “CostItem3”   500  1000  1500
```

Each row is then used in a triangular distribution function (library(triangle)) as follows over a number of iterations (runs = 10000 in this case):

```
CostItem1 <- rtriangle(runs, l, u, c)
```

I currently manually enter the range estimate data for each cost item (CostItem1, CostItem2 etc) in the rtriangle function.

## My question is:

How can I create a loop function or other approach to do this directly from the CSV file when it is read into R? As a newbie I have no idea how to tackle this and all of the Google searching has not revealed anything.

The cost item data is then merged in a new dataframe (TotalCostEstimate) which contains 10000 simulations and each row summed to provide the modelled total cost data (TotalCost):

```
 TotalCostEstimate<-data.frame(CostItem1 ,CostItem2 ,TotalCost=rowSums(x))
```

From here the data can be plotted and presented for analysis and decision making. For a small number of cost items, manually entering isn't too bad but I sometimes have rows > 50 and i don't want to do this 50+ times!!

Many thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather then doing it directly from the CSV you're better off reading the CSV into a matrix, creating your total cost matrix, and then running the for loop to simulate the values.

For example in this way:

```
runs<-1000 #Set number of runs
Info_costs<- read.csv( "Your_file_name.csv") #Read in the information
Total_cost_items<-matrix(,nrow=runs,ncol=length(Info_costs$Item)) #Create an empty matrix to contain your simulations
for (i in 1:length(Info_costs$Item))
   {Total_cost_items[,i]<-rtriangle(n=runs,Info_costs$l[i],Info_costs$u[i],Info_costs$c[i]) } 
#Fill the matrix
Total_cost_items<-data.frame(Total_cost_items, rowSums(Total_cost_items)) #append the matrix with the row sums
```

You may need to tweak the read.csv function with options and of course the correct file name such that it correctly reads your file.
Also you can rename the columns of the dataframe later to something more useful

Comment: Maarten, thank you this works really well. As you say, I will need to adjust the column names. Im thinking that I will base them on a row count of the CSV data to allow multiple items to be added and then create an 'n' row arrangement for easy naming.

Comment: @nick_dawe You're welcome. The column name sounds like a good idea, if you want to use the code later on an appended CSV. Not sure what you mean with a 'n' row arrangement

Answer (score 0):

You can read your data using `read.csv` and keep it as a `data.frame`. Here's some dummy data:

```
df <- data.frame(Item=letters[1:3], l=1:3, c=2:4, u=3:5)
df

  Item l c u
1    a 1 2 3
2    b 2 3 4
3    c 3 4 5
```

You can use `foreach` and `dplyr` to accomplish what you want:

```
library(foreach)
library(dplyr)

df <- foreach(I=1:nrow(df), .combine=rbind) %do% rtriangle(10,df$l[I],df$c[I],df$u[I]) %>%
as.data.frame() %>%
mutate( sum = rowSums(.))
```

This will iterate through each row of `df`, execute `rtriangle`, bind the resulting data into a `matrix`, convert the `matrix` into a `data.frame`, on which you can calculate `rowSums`.

**My Output**

```
   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 sum
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Chi Pak, thanks for your reply. When I ran your code it created 10 columns based on the rows. Maarten's code provided the answer I needed. Thanks again.

Comment: I think your answer would be found in the column `sum`, but glad you got your answer nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

## Solved - Thanks to @Maarten Punt!

Thought I would post the final working solution:

```
TotalCostEstimate<-matrix(,nrow=runs,ncol=length(basedata$Item)) #Create an empty matrix to contain your simulations
for (i in 1:length(basedata$Item)) # Prepare distributions based on the distribution type select (1 [triangle] or 2 [discrete])
{if (basedata$DistType[i] == 1) { 
        TotalCostEstimate[,i]<-rtriangle(n=runs,basedata$l[i],basedata$u[i],basedata$c[i]) 
}else{
        TotalCostEstimate[,i]<- sample(c(0,basedata$u[i]),runs,replace=TRUE)        
        }}
#Fill the matrix
TotalCostEstimate<-data.frame(TotalCostEstimate, rowSums(TotalCostEstimate)) #append the matrix with the row sums
for (i in 1:length(basedata$Item))
{colnames(TotalCostEstimate)[i]<-basedata$Item[i] } # Rename the column names to the cost items from base data
#Rename the last column based on the number of cost items
i<-length(basedata$Item)
colnames(TotalCostEstimate)[i+1]<-"TotalCost"
```

Important to note that I modified the CSV to include a new field 'DistType' which allows the user to select the type of distribution to use in the simulation - discrete (on or off) or triangular:

```
          Item     l     c     u DistType
            <chr> <int> <int> <int>    <int>
1     “CostItem1”  1500  1900  2600        1
2     “CostItem2”  2400  3200  4400        1
3     “CostItem3”   500  1000  1500        1
4 “DiscCostItem4”     0     0  1500        2
```

I also modified the loop function to take the cost item names of the CSV file and allocate them to the columns of the output with the last summed column [i+1] being named 'TotalCost'. This allowed the outputs/plots to be automatically titled (again using a loop) based on the column names.

Comment: Sorry shouldn't use my mobile dor this. I meant:  Nice but you don't actually need a loop for the column names. colnames(TotalCostEstimate)[1:length(basedata$Item)]<-basedata$Item should do the trick and speed up computation

Comment: Thanks again Maarten, will give it a try.